# I need to set different target for different users by using the mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to set different target for different users by using the mysql query. I have created the table with the name of Files18, this table has four columns (userid as varchar, team as varchar, department as varchar, Target as integer).

Now with the reference of UserId, I need to set the Target value.

Here is my query:

```
try{
                 String sql = "SELECT Target from Files18 where UserId= '"+text.getText()+"' ";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://193.168.2.251:3306/Transcription", "root", "root");
            PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet Rs = pstm.executeQuery();

            JT_Target = new JTextField(20); 
            JT_Target.setEnabled(false);
            JT_Target.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
            JT_Target.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            JT_Target.setText(String.valueOf(Rs.getInt("Target")));
             }
                catch(Exception ex){}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Any time you find yourself appending numerals to a table name, you have to consider whether your schema design might be seriously flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry,there is no problem with my schema design

Comment: @vasanth Please edit your question to elaborate your problem. It is not clear what the problem is and what you are trying to do. Please add a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: @Progman,I need to assign a value for the target(textfield) through my query String sql = "SELECT Target from Files18 where UserId= '"+JT_UserId.getText()+"' ";

Comment: @vasanth Please edit your question to include the source code you have (the full MVCE) and the specific problem you have why your current source code doesn't work.

Comment: @Progman,My Files18 table has four columns(userid as varchar,team as varchar,department as varchar,Target as integer)

Comment: @Progman,Is this clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding your created `JTextField` object to your GUI. You created an instance and set some properties (including the content), but you don't add it to your GUI by using the `add()` methods of your container like `JFrame` or `JPanel`.

Also, you must call the [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) method on your result set to jump to the first row in the result set. After that you can use the `get*()` methods to read the data from the current row. With additional `next()` calls you get to the following rows until you reach the end of the result set.

You have a try-catch block which catches every exception but you don't do anything with it. When there are any errors you don't see them. Maybe you have an exception right now but because you don't do anything in your catch block you don't see it. Rewrite your error handling to display or generate helpful error messages.

Additionally, that is not how you use prepared statements. To use variables inside a prepared statements you first create a prepared statements with `?` characters as placeholders for values in the query. The query should look like this:

```
SELECT Target from Files18 where UserId=?
```

When you have created your prepared statement you can use the `set*()` methods so insert the values for the query like this:

```
pstm.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(text.getText()));
```